# SQL Server - Group by, having and count in a mix

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I have a database with a long list of records. Most of the columns have foreign keys to other tables.

**Example**:

```
ID SectorId BranchId
-- -------- --------
5  3        5
```

And then I will have a table with sectors, branches ect.

**My issue**:

I want to know how many records which has sector 1, 2, 3 ... n. So what I want is a `group by Sector` and then some `count(*)` which will tell me how many there is of each.

**Expected output**

So for instance, if I have 20 records the result might look like this:

```
SectorId Count
-------- -----
1        3
2        10
3        4
4        6
```

**My attempts so far**

I do not normally work a lot with databases and I have been trying to solve this for 1.5 hours. I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Records r
GROUP BY r.Sector
WHERE r.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
```

But... errors and problems all over!

I would really appreciate some help. I do know this is probably very simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence of your query is not correct; it should be like this: -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Records r
WHERE r.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY r.Sector
```

The output will be only counts i.e.

```
count
-----
3
10
4
6
```

If you want to fetch both sector and count then you need to modify the query a little

```
SELECT r.Sector, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Records r
WHERE r.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY r.Sector
```

The output will be like this: -

```
Sector Count
------ -----
1      3
2      10
3      4
3      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query was partially right,But it needs some modification.

If I write this way:-

```
SELECT r.SectorID,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Records r
WHERE r.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY r.SectorID
```

Then output will be:-

```
SectorID  Count 
1           3
2          10
3           4
4           6
```